# Reducing number of splits in map reduce job using hadoop streaming jar.

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

How to reduce number of splits in map reduce job using hadoop streaming jar. I tried to modify mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize/maxsize but the number is still the same.

Number of split in my job is 85000 and job takes around 12 hours to complete. In order to reduce time, reducing number of split should be good option since launching a container is an expensive process.

Any other suggestions are also welcome regarding reducing job time apart from increasing the server.